# Highlight the index type in liquibase

Tags: methods, indexing, liquibase

I want to create an index on my MySql table, but i cannot find how to highlight the specific index type in 'createIndex' for all Available Attributes, 
So, how could i can do ?

Comment: such as I want to use BTREE or HASH, how could i specific the type

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase does not currently support specifying specific index types. To support it, there would need to be extra attributes in the XML and then the MySQL code in Liquibase would need to be updated to look for those attributes and generate the proper SQL. Ideally the MySQL code that inspects the database would also figure out what kind of index type was being used on existing indexes and generate the proper XML in a generated changelog.